# Exercise in Jurgen Jost: Show that if $u$ is harmonic then $v$ is harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^3-\{0\}}$ and $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ **harmonic in $\Omega$**. Show that $$v(x^1,x^2,x^3):=\dfrac{1}{|x|}u\Big(\dfrac{x^1}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^2}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^3}{|x|^2}\Big)$$ is **harmonic** in the region $\Omega' :=\{x\in \mathbb{R^3}:\Big(\dfrac{x^1}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^2}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^3}{|x|^2}\Big)\in \Omega\}$

**a. Is there a "deeper" reason for this?**

**b. Is there an analogous result for arbitrary dimension $d$?**

My solution for the first part is the following:

Because $\Delta(fg)=\Delta(f)g+f\Delta(g)+2\nabla f \nabla g$ then

$$\Delta v(x^1,x^2,x^3)=\Delta\Big(\dfrac{1}{|x|}\Big)u\Big(\dfrac{x^1}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^2}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^3}{|x|^2}\Big)+\dfrac{1}{|x|}\Delta u\Big(\dfrac{x^1}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^2}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^3}{|x|^2}\Big)+2\nabla\Big(\dfrac{1}{|x|}\Big)\nabla u\Big(\dfrac{x^1}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^2}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^3}{|x|^2}\Big)=2\nabla\Big(\dfrac{1}{|x|}\Big)\nabla u\Big(\dfrac{x^1}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^2}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^3}{|x|^2}\Big)$$ for $x'\in \Omega$. With $x'=\Big(\dfrac{x^1}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^2}{|x|^2},\dfrac{x^3}{|x|^2}\Big)$

Because $u$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ and $\dfrac{1}{|x|}$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R^3}-\{0\}$.

What can I do with the last term? (I assume that those vectors are orthogonal but don't know how to show it.)

Also I don't know what to do with questions **a** and **b**. Thanks in advance for any hints.